# Energy Saver on new A/C doesn't work well

Tags: air-conditioning, energy-efficiency

I just got a GE AEW12AM window a/c and the energy saver mode doesn't work that well.  I'm used to the in-wall a/c that usually run for a few minutes then turn off for ten.  This GE unit seems to turn off once it gets 2 degrees below the set temperature and comes back on when it gets to 2 degrees above your specified temp. So the a/c will run for a while until it gets to the temp, but then it turns off for at least 30-60 minutes even though it starts getting kinda hot.  Part of the problem I think is that the thermostat in the a/c gets varying temperatures.  How can I fix this?

Comment: The problem is the thermostat has a large swing between on and off points. 4 deg is too much IMO, but quite common. There is something to be said for appliances not cycling on and off frequently though. Some thermostats have adjustable swing, but they seem to be rather rare. If you can find an appliance with this feature, seriously consider buying it.

Comment: The $99 Wifi Filtrete thermostat from Homedepot has a configurable swing from 0.5 - 2 degrees

Comment: yea but i dont wanna spend another $100 after spending $350 on this a/c.  It should do as gunner mentioned below.  Unfortunately I've had it for a few weeks and threw out the box, guess i gotta call GE and see if they can do something.

Comment: I have a GE also. The problem is on most energy saver modes the fan comes back on. My GE doesn't and I'm pretty sure yours doesn't either. When mine shuts off the temp reading gets lower due to the coldness of the coils. I guess in the test facility GE has it worked fine but not in real life. I just leave mine on cool, sorry.

Comment: The problem is, it's doing exactly what it's designed to do. Either return it or turn off eco-mode.

Answer (score 4):

I would return it.

Energy saving modes work like this:
You set the temp and the fan and compressor run until the room is cooled to that temperature +/- a few degrees.  Once the set temperature is reached, the compressor AND fan shut off.  Every 2-5 minutes (each manufacture is different) ONLY the fan will turn on to get the room air circulating though the unit to check the temperature.  If the room got hotter, then the compressor and fan will turn on to cool and turn off when done. Repeat cycle.

Where as the normal mode the fan and compressor come on, and once the temperature is reached, the compressor turns off but the fan stays on continuously.